# Why do we do electrolysis and electroplating using warm electrolyte?

Tags: electrochemistry, electrolysis, conductivity, electroplating

This is a pretty basic question, and I know it has something to do with conductivity, but I'm not quite sure how they are related.

Comment: Blake, please see my edits -- if you're unhappy with anything I changed, please feel free to change it back, or roll back my edit entirely.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reasoning here is two-fold. The [solubility of *most* electrolytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solubility#Temperature) increases with temperature, and [water's ionization constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-ionization_of_water#Dependence_on_temperature.2C_pressure_and_ionic_strength) also increases with temperature. On the whole this means more ions, and thereby better conductivity.

Comment: Can you clarify on the ionization constant because I thought it decreased when temperature increased.

Comment: @jakekimds The value of $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ does decrease with increasing temperature, yes. But, this means that the proper ionization constant, $K_\mathrm{a}$, *increases* with increasing temperature.

Answer (score 8):

ringo makes good points in [his answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/67398/11367). Additionally, though, the increased temperature enhances mass transfer of ions to/from the electrode surfaces by at least two mechanisms:

1. Higher temperature results in lower electrolyte [viscosity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viscosity), leading to a thinner fluid dynamic [boundary layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_layer) and concomitant greater mass transfer to/from the electrode surfaces.
2. Higher temperature also increases the [diffusivities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusivity) of the electrolyte solutes, which also contributes to increased mass transfer to/from the electrodes.

Comment: very good additional points.